# JSON.parse fails with valid JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am developing an application in which I need to send over a large JSON - about 7M characters (6.6 MB of data). The JSON is correctly received as string, but when I try to parse it with JSON.parse, I get an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

I have plugged the JSON into JSONLint, and it says that it is valid. How do I go around debugging this?

I made a [dump](http://213.136.81.218/dump.html) of the json, for those interested. It is mesh data of a 3D structure.

Comment: 7... million.... characters.....? That's around 14Mb (depending on encoding), I don't believe that can't be truncated/paged. I would look to fix that issue first before worrying about any parsing problems stemming from the sheer weight of the data.

Comment: Are you sure it is string representation of `JSON` ?

Comment: what are 7M characters?

Comment: Which parser (browser?) says that it is invalid?

Comment: What you will do 7M json string

Comment: @NinaScholz This usually refers to a [million](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Million). That's actually some 7 MB of data if it is mostly latin characters encoded as UTF8, that's not that much really.

Comment: @Lucero, thank you, but it should be a string?

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes, a string of 7 MB which should be converted to an object representation using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) I guess.

Comment: is it **14MB** or **7MB** just wondering :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it could, and it probably will in the future, but it will take some time to implement. Is that the problem? I'd think that once the whole string makes its way to the browser, then the parsing should happen easily...

Comment: @Lucero that's correct. I'm working on Google Chrome right now.

Comment: Is the data sensitive? Or could you provide access to the API / file somehow  (if its not sensitive)

Comment: @RohanBüchner I've added a link to the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 7M characters (assuming mostly latin) translates to some 7MB of UTF8 data or 14MB of UTF16 data. Todays browsers can handle that fine, therefore I think that your data gets corrupted somewhere along the way from the server to the code part where you actually parse it.

Maybe output the string to a HTML `textarea` and run that again in JSONLint.

Comment: Just tried that, it is still valid according to JSONLint. Chrome says it is 6.6 MB of data. By the way, I noticed that this question has been downvoted, why is that?

Comment: @user1846231 my 5 cents, so I could be wrong... (Some) SO users tend to be a bit judgmental of questions that come across as "do my work for me", not saying that's what you're doing it, but this platform can be a bit harsh toward new users at the best times. (Think it's a combination of you having lower rep, and it being a text only question with no code sample)

Comment: @user1846231 When I browse to the URL you provided, open my Dev Tools (F12) and enter the following command in the console, the JSON parses just fine: `JSON.parse(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerText)`

Comment: Turned out you were right, the last thing you said made me check once more and the string I was receiving from the server had some \0 chars padded at the end, which were breaking the parse. I didn't notice the small length difference, thanks.